# Friendly url when clicking news headline

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

For last 4 days I´ve been trying to make a friendly url using .htaccess (mod_rewrite)

I have a some news on frontpage and link redirects to the full article on news_id.php

So `mypage.com/local/news_id.php?newsid=37` should take the headline from the "headline" field
in phpmyadmin - for example `mypage.com/local/police-stops-girl-fight-at-the-mall`

my .htaccess code is

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^local/([^/.]+)/?$/local/news_id.php?headline=$1 [L]
```

Some tutorials says I also have to edit the php link on frontpage which is

```
<a href="local/news_id.php?newsid=<?php echo $row['newsid'] ?>"><?php echo $row ['headline']?</a>
```

...but I've also stumbled on articles that says that I don´t need it and show this should do
it.

I've checked out if mod_rewrite is enabled at the server and it works fine.

Am I close or is this much more complicated than I think?

Comment: I think you should edit the php files too.

Answer (score 1):

Previously you were fetching by id.  Now you are attempting to fetch by title.

That's a fundamental difference in the way your article lookups will need to occur and what content will be in your urls.

It may be easier to start out with a simple experiment site.  Get that working.  Then convert your real site over once you've seen how it all works.

Comment: ok, thanx for the information. Doing the simple try is easy but as soon as I try to blend in the mysql with it, nothing works.
Think I hire a professional - too much time gone :)

Comment: I think you're probably having the problem with mysql with the queries.  Before you were probably doing something like "blah blah where id = $newsid" You can't just swap in the title of the article.  You need to either look up by title (where title = $title) or get the id from the title and use that in the query.